# Div data Highlight issue

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs aligned in parallel, each div contains 2 paragraphs (div1 > 1 2 and div2 > 3 4). 
I want to highlight only the 4th paragraph (`<p style=background-color:blue>4year</p>`) but it always affects the 2nd paragraph as well. How can I fix this issue?

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<div id="select-year-col1" style="float:left;">
    <p class="font-color">1 year</p>
    <p class="font-color">2 year</p>
</div>
<div id="select-year-col2">
    <p class="font-color">3 year</p>
    <p class="font-color" style="background-color:blue">4 year</p>
</div>
```

Comment: post css code which you used to highlight the div

Comment: there are no quote on style attribute on the p

Comment: looks highlighted to me, what's the problem SPN? http://jsbin.com/yudez/1/edit

Comment: Doesn't highlight 2 here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aA99w/

Comment: Plese check this code and let me know. how to highlight 4th year data only

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but what I've understood from the question, you dhould try:-

```
<div id="select-year-col1" style="float:left;">
  <p class="font-color">1 year</p>
  <p class="font-color">2 year</p>
</div>
<div id="select-year-col2" style="float:left;">
  <p class="font-color">3 year</p>
  <p class="font-color" style="background-color:blue">4 year</p>
</div>
```